# Docker container hangs up after sometime, not able to execute any command on container

Tags: docker, containers, freeze, fifo

I am trying to find the root cause about a Docker container hang up issue. Please find below my observations:

- not able to execute `docker logs, docker exec, docker stop, docker rm, docker inspect, docker stats` commands on that container.
- However, able to execute above commands on other running containers.
- `docker rmi <any img ID>` not working.
- docker logs shows error something like-

> level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"

**Note:-** I researched the problem, but not found suitable solution other than restarting a Docker service.

System info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-141-generic
- Docker: 17.12.0-ce

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that can demonstrate the issue?  Given what you've described and absent any code, my first recommendation would in fact be to restart the Docker daemon (and my second to upgrade the system to something newer).

Comment: Its an intermittent issue, I observed. Couldn't able to reproduce it. Limiting the CPU and memory will work for me?